# scikit-learn: classifying texts using custom labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, naivebayes

I have a large training set of words labeled `pos` and `neg` to classify texts. I used TextBlob (according to [this tutorial](http://stevenloria.com/how-to-build-a-text-classification-system-with-python-and-textblob/)) to classify texts. While it works fairly well, it can be very slow for a large training set (e.g. 8k words).

I would like to try doing this with `scikit-learn` but I'm not sure where to start. What would the above tutorial look like in `scikit-learn`? I'd also like the training set to include weights for certain words. Some that should pretty much guarantee that a particular text is classed as "positive" while others guarantee that it's classed as "negative". And lastly, is there a way to imply that certain parts of the analyzed text are more valuable than others?

Any pointers to existing tutorials or docs appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent chapter on this topic in [Sebastian Raschka's Python Machine Learning book](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book) and the code can be found here: https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/code/ch08/ch08.ipynb.

He does sentiment analysis (what you are trying to do) on an IMDB dataset. His data is not as clean as yours - from the looks of it - so he needs to do a bit more pre-processing work. Your problem can be solved with these steps:

1. Create numerical features by vectorizing your text: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html
2. Train test split: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html
3. Train and test your favourite model, e.g.: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: Good resources, thank you; I do need to buy that book! One question: if my training set is literally just single words labeled with a boolean value (does not matter what each represents), is it still possible to build out a classifier to use for multi-sentence texts? I get the impression that the models work by analyzing entire texts, creating tables of probabilities and then applying set heuristics on the input texts.

Comment: The hashing vectorizer uses TF-IDF to assign numerical values to words. The TF part will only care about each sample - so it will be 1 for each of your samples. The IDF part compares each sample to all samples and that is how your numerical features will be created. Since you will try to predict sentiment from a single numerical feature you could overlay histograms (coloured by sentiment) and see how well it's going to work before you train any model.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this like Tf-Idf (Term frequency - Inverse Document Frequency), Count Vectorizer, Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA), Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA), Word2Vec.

Among all of above mentioned methods, Word2Vec is the best method. You can use a pre-trained model by Google for Word2Vec, available on:

https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors